Integer Array is empty for no reason
So I have this code that is supposed to generate a random 4 digit code. It correctly prints out each generated number but when I try to print out the entire array, its empty. Or at least it doesnt print anything out...
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CODE_LENGTH 4

void generate_code(int code[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < CODE_LENGTH; i++) {
        int x = rand() % 10;
        printf("\n%i", x);
        code[i] = x;
    }
    printf("\nCode: %n", code);
}

int main(void)
{
    int code[4];

    generate_code(code);
    
    return 0;
}

Output:
1
7
4
0
Code: 


What is the meaning of this conversion specifier %n?

Where did you read (or get the idea) that printf("%n") could be used to print out arrays? See e.g. Is there a way to have printf() properly print out an array

@Nebelmonster You can output elements of an integer array only in a loop.

@Nebelmonster Pay attention to that you should use function srand before using the function rand.

Unrelated: a "line" is commonly defined as "a sequence of characters terminated by and including a 'newline'". To make it easy for your program to talk to other programs... gain the habit of terminating your printfs withs "\n", not starting them so, ie use printf("...%i...etc...\n", a, b, c, ...);

An array can never be empty in C. It has a defined size and every entry holds some value. These values might be indetermined if you do not initialize your array, but they are not empty.

Side note: for a four-digit array, an array of char would be better suited than an array of int.  And if you also generate the digits as digit characters instead of digit numbers (e.g. code[i] = x + '0') then you will be able to print the whole result at once as character sequenc, using format specifier '%.4s.

Alternatively, it seems a bit baroque to generate the digits individually or to store them in an array.  How about instead generating a single random int in the range 0 - 9999?  You can then print it in one go with %04d to get leading zeroes as appropriate.

There are several problems with your code.
The first one is that even you defined the constant CODE_LENGTH
#define CODE_LENGTH 4

the array declared in main uses the magic number 4 instead of the constant
int main(void)
{
    int code[4];
    //...

Moreover the array is not used in main. At least you should output the filled in the function generate_code array in main. That is the function should do only one thing: to fill a passed to it array.
Also before using the function rand you should call function srand.
There is no such a conversion specifier that allows to output a whole array in one call of printf except character arrays. To output an integer array you need to use a loop inside which each element of the array will be outputed in turn.
The conversion specifier n is designed for entirely other task. As it is written in the C Standard

n The argument shall be a pointer to signed integer into which is written the number of characters written to the output stream so far
by this call to fprintf. No argument is converted, but one is
consumed. If the conversion specification includes any flags, a field
width, or a precision, the behavior is undefined.

Your program can look the following way
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define CODE_LENGTH 4

void generate_code( int code[], size_t n )
{
    const int Base = 10;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        code[i] = rand() % Base;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int code[CODE_LENGTH];

    generate_code( code, CODE_LENGTH );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < CODE_LENGTH; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d", code[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' ); 
}

Or you could use a character array to store the generated code. For example
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define CODE_LENGTH 4

void generate_code( char code[], size_t n )
{
    const int Base = 10;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        code[i] = rand() % Base + '0';
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char code[CODE_LENGTH];

    generate_code( code, CODE_LENGTH );
    
    printf( "%.*s\n", CODE_LENGTH, code );
}

Or you could declare the character array as an array that will contain a string. For example
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define CODE_LENGTH 4

void generate_code( char code[], size_t n )
{
    const int Base = 10;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        code[i] = rand() % Base + '0';
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char code[CODE_LENGTH + 1] = "";

    generate_code( code, CODE_LENGTH );
    
    printf( "%s\n", code );
}


The %n format specifier is actually used to read the number of characters written so far, so this won't do what you expect.
You can't print the contents of an array with a single statement.  You have to loop through it.
printf("\nCode: ");
for(i = 0; i < CODE_LENGTH; i++) {
    printf("%i ", code[i]);
}
printf("\n");


There is no conversion specifier for printf that can magically print an array, because there is no way for printf to know the size of the array. You have to loop and print the items one by one, by using %d for int items.
So %n doesn't do what you think it does. What it is actually used for is to store the number of characters written so far to stdout. Example:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int count;
  printf("Hello%n world!\n", &count);
  printf("Hello consisted of %d characters printed.", count);
}

In this case count becomes 5. And this is probably a mildly useful feature for most people. But you get no input because %n alone doesn't give any output. Your program instead stored the number of characters printed into your array, which is not what you want.
